# Find volume bounded by curve $x=\sqrt {25-y^2}$, and the line $x=3$, rotated about the $y$-axis

Tags: calculus, volume

My attempt:

$$2\pi\int_0^{5} (25-y^2) dy$$

What's my error?

Comment: Well you forgot about the $x = 3$ part.

Comment: do the bounds from 0 to 5 cover the x=3 part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

$x = 3$ and $x = \sqrt{25-y^2}$ intersect at $y = 4$ and $-4$

$$V = \pi \int_{-4}^{4} (25-y^2 - 9)dy = \pi \int_{-4}^{4} (16-y^2)dy$$

if you evaluate the integral you get $V = \frac{256\pi}{3}$

The Shell method of solving:

Radius $= x$ and height = $2\sqrt{25-x^2}$

$V = 2\pi \int_{3}^{5} 2x\sqrt{25-x^2}dx = \frac{256\pi}{3}$

[image]

Comment: Volume = the integral of the area. I think that the area from bounded by x=$\sqrt(25-\sqrt(y^2)$ and the line x=3 is $\int_0^5 \sqrt(25-\sqrt(x^2)$ The upper bound of 5 comes from the fact that at y=5, of the squareroot function, x=3. Is my thinking incorrect?

Comment: I am using the ring method and your curve I assume is $\sqrt{25-y^2}$ and the $Volume = \pi \int_{-4}^{4} \left[(Outer radius)^2 - (inner radius)^2\right]dy$.  Here in this case, outer radius = $\sqrt{25-y^2}$ and the innner radius 3.  Now apply and you get the result.

Comment: how is the inner radius 3? I thought it was 0 as the distance from the y-axis to the line x=3 is defined by my curve's function.

Comment: See the picture and you will realize that the volume is the region bounded by x =3 as the inner radius and $\sqrt{25-y^2}$ as the outer radius.

Comment: The line you drew with an arrow pointing at x=3 is actually y=3. What does the bottom line represent?

Comment: Not at all, the line that I draw is x = 3 implying for all values of y x = 3 that is what it means.

Comment: that would be a vertical line and not a horizontal line

Comment: Now I understand, the vertical line is x = 3, and the inner radius is 3 and the outer radius is $\sqrt{25-y^2}$.  The radius are measured in terms of distance from x = 3 to y axis and the outer radisu to be the distance of $\sqrt{25-y^2}$ from the y axis as the axis of rotation is y axis.  I did not realize that the you interpreted x = 3 to be the arrowed line.  Sorry.

Comment: I think that x=3 is just a boundary, a border, a limit for the outer radius. I don't understand how it is the inner radius. Is the region that we're revolving via the ring method bounded by the area of the curve x=$\sqrt {25-y^2}$ from x = 0 to 3?

Comment: can we use shells on this problem? Let's write it in terms of  y and use dx; can that make it easier to explain?

Comment: I don't have a sophisticated software to illustrate the working of the ring method, but the region blacked in the picture is rotated about the y-axis. Now understand what is the inner radius and the outer radius

Comment: I have given the shell method's answer.   If you have any question, let me know.

Comment: how do you get the bounds of x=3 to 5 for the shell method? I think it should be from x = 0 to 3

Answer (score 0):

You must subtract the area of the segment formed by the $x=3$. Try taking the integrals in sections:

- The integral of {the circle minus the line}
- Subtract that from the total integral of the circle

Comment: Does doubling the integral from 0 to 5 make up for not setting the bounds from -5to5 because the graph is symmetrical?

Comment: Oh, that's true. My bad. Not how I would have done it, but certainly not incorrect.